# variable does not compare to x and x

Tags: comparison

hi I am trying to find out if a 'var' is not equal to more than one number; 
but the '!=' seems to only allow for one number.  is there a work around?
thanks: )

```
if(lineNum != 100, 103) 
{
  $("#pic1-div").animate({
     left: "+=150"
  }, 1000  );
```

thanks to Klyarash for the answer below : )

i cant see where to thumbs up or vote 'answered' but this did the trick!!! : )

Comment: use &&...!!! if (lineNum != 100 && lineNum != 103 )...

Comment: thank you very much Klyarash!!! : P  : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic operands like AND->(***`&&`***) either OR->(**`||`**)...

try this if it's important for you that the `lineNum` wasn't equal to both numbers:

```
if(lineNum != 100 && lineNum != 103) 
  {
      $("#pic1-div").animate({
         left: "+=150"
      }, 1000  );
  }
```

OR try this if you want one of two numbers:

```
  if(lineNum != 100 || lineNum != 103) 
      {
          $("#pic1-div").animate({
             left: "+=150"
          }, 1000  );
      }
```

Comment: hi, to vote up I need a reputation , but i have added a note in the main area of the page. thanks again, Dr. Klyarash my head ache has gone lol : ) !!

Comment: LOL... just hit the tick under the vote area... thank God... ;)